# MVC Attribute Routing RoutePrefix does not work with default routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a work-around, but I'd really like to know why this doesn't appear to work in MVC. (.Net 4.6.1)

I have a controller which I want to use a RoutePrefix:

```
[RoutePrefix("entry")]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(), Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the route config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "entry", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The issue is that with this configuration, running under local IIS to test, navigating to "localhost/testApp/entry" works, "localhost/testApp/entry/index" works, however the default "localhost/testApp/" results in a 404.

This has been doing my head in because on a fresh project with the default controllers and a default set to "home" and "index" the "localhost/testApp" would render Home/Index without an issue.

I narrowed it down to the `RoutePrefix` being the issue. If I remove the `RoutePrefix` and change the defaults to: `new { controller = "default", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Then "localhost/testApp" works, but obviously this requires using /default for other routes rather than /entry.

Also, if I leave the prefix in (switching the default controller back to "entry") and add `Route("~/")` to the `Index` method, then "localhost/testApp" also works as according to the doco that a ~ route overrides the route prefix.

I'd like to know if there is an explanation why RoutePrefix doesn't seem to play nice with default routing? I'm fine with adding a ~/ route for that default action, but it seems I'm missing some understanding on how RoutePrefix is intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Action attribute routing has the highest priority. If you use it only route attributes will be working, everything else will be ignored. You can to one action as many routes  as you need.

Since you have  2 variants - Route() and Route("Index") it works only for 2 urls -"localhost/testApp/entry" and  "localhost/testApp/entry/index".

if you remove Route() it will work only for one url-lcalhost/testApp/entry/index".

If you add 3rd Route("~/") it will work for  3rd  url "localhost/testApp"
Sign ~ means that any prefixes should be ignored, it starts from root.

So you can not use default conventional routing on Index action since it is only obeys routing attributes.

Also, you have a controller [RoutePrefix("entry")] attribute routing too and it that  next highest priority and  because of this it overrides your convention routing in the config file. This is why default routing doesn't work for this controller and it doesn't go to Index automaticaly. To make default route work you need to remove route prefix and fix web config

```
defaults: new { controller = "default", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Current default controller = "entry" doesn't exist at all.

So you have two choices to have Index as default route action - remove all attribute routing and lost all another extra routes  or add one more.

Comment: That is consistent with what I observed, but I guess the question is why with that setup the "defaults:" default route setup set for 'entry/index" does *not* seem to be considered when "/entry/index" is a configured route? If I rely on convention routing (with an EntryController) that default says "if nothing is specified, go to /entry/index") My prefixed routing does support /entry/index yet resolving the default results in a 404.

Comment: This just reiterates the work-around that I had figured out, The explanation I'm looking for help to track down is *why* the Default routing (declared after AttributeRouting as documented it should be) cannot resolve a RoutePrefixed route?  entry/index is a valid route with the prefix, but why can the "defaults" not resolve it? (As opposed to the work-around of forcing that action route to map to Root). I can find no doco stating "defaults" can only apply to convention/config-based routes. Attribute & config routes can work together as long as configs are declared after `MapMvcAttributeRoutes`

Comment: @StevePy I am sorry , I am not a professor,  i am a practical man. I was just trying to explain that default routing will never be working even if you remove all attributes  since current default controller "entry" doesn't exist. Prefix name it is not a  new controller name. Index automatically works only with homecontroller

Comment: No, and Yes, you did help me work out what is going on.. Namely this: "Prefix name it is not a new controller name"  I did a bit more digging and applying a [Route] to an action effectively excludes it entirely from controller/action mappings, even with a matcing prefix. Having just `[Route("Index")] with no RoutePrefix and "localhost/testApp/default/index"  doesn't work, only "localhost/testApp/index" So RoutePrefix does not substitute a /controller mapping, the {controller}/{action} route simply doesn't get matched to apply a default for. Thanks for highlighting my bad assumption!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Serge for helping point out a bad assumption I had about `[RoutePrefix]`. The problem here turns out that `[RoutePrefix]` is not a substitute name for a controller, (though that is how it behaves on the surface) but rather a prefix to each individual action. While the mapping in the URL will be identical:

Example 1:

```
public class EntryController
{
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }
}
```

Example 2:

```
[RoutePrefix("Entry")]
public class DefaultController
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }
}
```

Both of these examples would resolve "localhost/testApp/entry/index", however only the first mapping would be considered as a match for {controller}/{action} and resolve a "defaults" mapping of "entry/index".

So if an action /w Attribute-based routing needs to be made a root default you need to explicitly declare it as the root using `[Route()]` if there is no `[RoutePrefix]`, or [Route("~/")] if there is a `[RoutePrefix]`. since it won't be included in the {controller}/{action} routing.  (Verified by removing the Default {controller}/{action} routing entirely).